# How are python variable names resolved? (explanations on the web are a bit uncertain)

Tags: python, callstack, pythoninterpreter

It seems that there are two things that are not being distinguished in some guides about this.

When a function is *running*, there is its local scope, and some scopes above her on call stack. Each scope has its local variables.

When a function is *defined*, there is also a call stack with scopes.

So when we reference a variable in the function, its name is resolved via rule LEGB. Does that rule apply to call stack of when it was *defined*, or the current call stack when it is *running*? I think it's the first one:

```
def f():
    y = 'when_defined'
    
    def g():
        print(y)
    
    return g
 
def h(g):
    y = 'when_running'
    g()
 
g = f()
h(g)
```

```
>>> when_defined
```

But in case when it comes to global variables, they don't have to be defined when the function is being defined, and can still be looked up

```
def h():
    print(x)
 
x = 1
h()
```

```
>>> 1
```

So my understanding is:

1. When the function is defined, it decides for itself which of used in it variables are local (namely if they are write-encountered in the code, or are in args), which of the other ones are from enclosed scopes (and save an object for those names in `fun.__closure__`). Other variables don't get a classification (but can then only be looked up in global or builtins). Operators `nonlocal`, `global` force the type of variable they are used on to be "first possible from EGB", and "global", respectvely.
2. When the function is running, and resolving a read on variable name, it first looks if it is a "local"-classified variable or not. If it is, it gives it from `locals()` (and fails if it wasn't assigned yet). Otherwise if it is "enclosed", gives the value from `fun.__closure__`. Then, it looks for it in `globals()`. And if its not there, in `builtins()`.

Is this understanding correct? Could you give me a place where I can look for the exact behaviour of this?

Is it also true that when doing an `import`, we are running a new module, so it can't be referencing anything above in the call stack, because its definition basically has no upper context? And we can simply say that it runs on its own, and then `import` adds its `locals()` to our `locals()`?

Comment: The behaviour is always the same: *lexical scope.* Closures are a special thing to make lexical scope behaviour work in situations like your first example.

Comment: But it isn't lexical with global variables, is it? A function can be even not defined yet, but used in definition. Also my question asks whether my understanding of how reads/writes are treated correct. Could you verify all points that I wrote (I don't want to infer wrong behaviour from just "lexical scope")

Comment: What exactly *is* “global” from the perspective of the function *is* determined lexically, i.e. as written. Where and how the function is called has no influence; that’s what lexical means here. That the thing referred to only needs to exist at call time, not time of definition, doesn’t change that.